# Issue related to import/export with typings

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have JS file and want to write typings for it.

```
import { ApiService }  from './src/ApiService'
```

Then I write typings and export it

```
   export declare class ApiService {
     constructor(adapter: any, options: any);
     on:(evt, cb) => any;
     extend: (opts) => any;
}
```

> error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of ApiService

How can I fix It?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your declaration in a file `ApiService.d.ts` (but the keyword `declare` is unnecessary):

```
// src/ApiService.d.ts
export class ApiService {
  constructor(adapter: any, options: any);
  on:(evt, cb) => any;
  extend: (opts) => any;
}
```

Notice that the TS definition file name must be the same as the JavaScript file name: `ApiService.d.ts` describes a JavaScript file `ApiService.js`.

Then, import it:

```
// test.ts
import { ApiService }  from './src/ApiService'
```

It should works.